# Forward from VPN to non-VPN network

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, site-to-site-vpn, google-kubernetes-engine, vpc-peering

I want to connect an existing Kubernetes cluster to remote VPN that uses only a specific subnet IP range. I could create a custom-mode VPC network within my project that only has the appropriate subnet defined and create the VPN tunnel within that network, but is there a forwarding solution that will send over packets to my original Kubernetes (default) VPC network? I read about VPC peering, but the IP ranges between the VPN network and Kubernetes Engine default VPC network may overlap, so I need a different routing solution.

[Network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u5QZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you would like to connect your existing GKE cluster (in default VPC) to a remote service over the VPN connection. In such a scenario, you can leverage [Google Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview) to connect between your GCP resource (GKE cluster) and on-premise (remote service) network subnet. Please note that no IP overlapping is accepted on both sides of the VPN tunnel.

It is not possible to route traffic destined for one VPC over the VPN, to another VPC network. Also, VPC network peering will not work here as VPN in a network can't be reached from a [peered network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering#vpns_not_reachable_across_peered_networks). Moreover, subnet IP range cannot overlap with another subnet IP range in a peered VPC network.